# Free analogue of the PostSharp required

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, aop, postsharp

I have heard of PostSharp, but I am wondering if there are any other similar tools - anything analogous to PostSharp?

Are there any libraries that could be used as an alternative to PostSharp? Any other tools that can post-process an assembly and inject code based on attributes?

Any free and/or open source alternatives to PostSharp would be especially interesting.

Thank you.

Comment: Does anyone know what "analogue of PostSharp" means?

Comment: @Gabe: analogue means "something comparable", in context it means a suitable substitute.

Comment: I've meant the alternative tools which can be used instead of PostSharp.
Sorry, I wrote so because of my mentality. In Russian language we use the word 'analogue' much more often than 'alternative'. And the other reason is my poor knowledge of English.

Comment: it's an acceptable use of the word. @Gabe if you use Chrome, here's a great extension which makes dictionary lookup easy https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja

Comment: mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja is a great name for a dictionary extension! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [CciSharp](http://ccisamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CciSharp&referringTitle=Home), but it's not really production quality yet.

P.S. By "not production quality", I don't mean you can't use it in production (you certainly can), but rather that the program and its API are part of a library (CCI) that has regular compatibility-breaking updates.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I've heard also about the Mono.Cecil but it's very low-level tool and is almost unusable in the projects having strong time restrictions.

Answer (score 5):

We also had a need for a free alternative to PostSharp for some open source libraries we are developing that required composition and other "professional" features of PostSharp requiring license fees.  Since we did not want to create open source software that was not actually free, I started working with the Microsoft.Cci libraries on [CodePlex](http://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/) .  These libraries support absolutely everything that PostSharp does and then some (you could create an entire assembly from scratch if you wanted).  In fact, the PostSharp website lists this as an alternative.

I am not sure the status of the CciSharp project mentioned above, but it is based on these libraries.

The downside of using Microsoft.Cci for the casual developer is these libraries are so powerful that they end up being extremely difficult to use.  For this reason, I started an open source project called [Afterthought](https://github.com/vc3/Afterthought) that leverages Microsoft.Cci, but provides a simple API footprint and requires no knowledge of Cci or dependencies on it to work.

My recommendation would be to use the PostSharp community edition if the feature set matches your needs, as this is a mature solution with decent performance.  If you are brave and need to perform some complex mods, use the Microsoft.Cci libraries.  If you are somewhere in between and are willing to help provide feedback on feature sets, give Afterthought a try.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes, we have decided to use the Community Edition of the PostSharp because its features cover all we need. But it is nice to know about some other tools also!

Answer (score 4):

PostSharp Community Edition?  It's free.

Comment: Wow. I have not ever thought of different editions. Thank you for the hint.
But what about the initial question? Do you know the same dev tools?

Comment: @keykeeper: You haven't told us what it is about PostSharp you don't like, so how can we recommend something that fits your needs better?

Comment: I haven't asked for something better. I just asked for an alternative tool which can make the same things.

Comment: For C# and .NET there isn't a tool that is on the same level.

Answer (score 0):

[Afterthought](https://github.com/vc3/Afterthought/wiki): new alternative, seems promising

Comment: https://github.com/vc3/Afterthought/wiki